# Android Emulator - Finding Port Number

Tags: android, emulation, telnet

I am running Android Studio with Microsoft's Visual Studio Emulator for Android on Windows 10. (I cannot use the default emulator due to an issue I am having with Intel HAXM)

Is anyone able to tell me an easy way of finding the port number that an emulated device is running on? I need to connect to the emulator through Telnet in order to send SMS commands.

Comment: IMO, default port can be 5555, you can read [more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx). If it is not correct, pls read [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Usually, `adb devices` command will tell you emulator port:
[image: port]

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to navigate to my ADB install directory to use this command.

Comment: yes, mine is configured in environment variable `path`

Comment: Works in Mac terminal too from the console in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In case you encounter the error :

'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Go for : https://www.baswijdenes.com/portfolio/telnet-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Then follow the normal procedure.